# What is the correct terminology to be used when talking about % changes?

Tags: percentages

Throughout my life, I read a "60% increase in x" as $ 60\% * x + x $. For example, if a question asked, "If the initial value of Gold was $39, 162 and if it increased by 50%, what is the price now?", I'd add 50% of 39,162 to get 58, 743.

Now, if I was asked to describe this change, I'd say "The price of Gold increased by 50%". Recently, while I was going through the manual of a calculator though, it said this:

[image]

That is, it is describing the "incease in weight" as a 160% increase -- while to me it's just a 60% increase ($ \frac {300}{500} = 0.6 $). What is right terminology to use? To me, a 160% increase is not the same as a 60% increase.  It'd make more sense to say that it *changed* by 160%.

Are both terminologies accepted (increased by 60% vs increased by 160%)? If so, how do we avoid confusion?

Comment: That’s odd. The percentage change of $a$ to $b$ is found by $\big(\frac{b-a}{a}\cdot 100\big)$%. In that example, the percentage change is $60$%, not $160$%. $500$ is $160$% of $300$, but that’s not the same as percentage increase, since it includes the initial $100$% of the original value.

Comment: The manual is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I've added an answer myself to this question to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual is wrong. In the example given in the question, the percentage change is 60%, not 160%.

(*Credts: users KM101 and Jens in the comments*).